# Swift Double - divide with 2 decimal places

Tags: swift

**I want it to show 2 decimal places.. e.g. when in put is 3/4 it should show 0.75 however it is showing 0.0 - not giving any errors..**

````
   ```
    func calculator() {
      let a = Int(readLine()!)! //First input
      let b = Int(readLine()!)! //Second input


       divide(n1: a, n2: b)

    }


     func divide(n1:Int, n2:Int){

      print(Double(n1/n2))

     }


     calculator()
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 3 and 4 is `Int`. When you divide `Int` you get 0 and you convert it to `Double`, you get 0.0

You need to either convert `n1` and `n2` to Double first

```
print(Double(n1)/Double(n2))
```

or have `n1` and `n2` as a `Double` parameter

```
func divide(n1: Double, n2: Double) {
   let result = round(100*(n1/n2)/100) // 2 decimal places 
}
```